# Insert content of div into Rails record

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a list of editable `<div>`s on a form in Rails like so:

```
<div id="article14" style="display: block;">Content one</div>
<div id="article15" style="display: block;">Content two</div>
<div id="article16" style="display: block;">Content three</div>
```

Should a user make a change to the content of one I want to send that change through my controller into a new Rails record. I already have the record being created, I just need the application to record the changes instead of the original from which it came. So the changes in, say, `<div id="article16">Changed content</div>` should be saved into `@edit.body` below.

```
 def create
    @doc = Doc.new(params[:doc])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @doc.save
        #make editable version
          if current_user.brand.try(:editable?)
            @doc.articles.each do |article|
              @edit = Edit.new
              @edit.body = article.body
              @edit.article_id = article.id
              @edit.doc_id = @doc.id
              @edit.user_id = current_user.id
              @edit.save
            end
          end
        @doc.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
        format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc.user.ftp, @doc) }
        format.json { render json: @doc, status: :created, location: @doc }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @doc.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any ideas? Maybe it's a case for jQuery? I'm not sure. Cheers!

Comment: If you want to do it on page submit, then save the DIV value into a hidden input field and on POST get the values from request params. But if you want a *live* save, then create a timer based function or 'done editing' button to trigger a ajax 'post' to the controller with just the DIV content.

Comment: I considered a hidden input, but because `@edit` is saved into a different model I don't really know how to name it or anything.

Comment: As of now, how do you update your articles? post them to a controller with 'update method'? If that is the case, then point your jQuery based 'post' to the same controller. Your page should have hidden values with article id, doc id OR an js array with those values; from which the jQuery post method can get them.

Comment: I don't update articles from this form. Articles are used like a template from which users can make adjustments to be saved into Edits.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do in-place editing. There are a number of gems that facilitate this, but there's [a RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) on doing it with the best-in-place gem.

Comment: Sort of! But I'm making a _copy_ of the article in the process by saving `@edit`, I don't want to edit the original.